# Add an answer reference in a question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Sometimes I see a field in a question that contains a message like this: how can I add this message to a question from another user?

[image]

Comment: Add the message?? Just flag the question as duplicate of another suitable question, thats it..

Comment: Yes, that's the point! Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a notice that is shown to the question OP as soon as a duplicate flag/close vote is raised. This is visible only to the question OP.

So to add this notice just flag as a duplicate.

If it is ultimately closed then a similar notice is displayed to everyone

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]